# What replication options exist between SQL Server 2000 and 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication, sql-server

We have a business partner that is still on SQL Server 2000, and we would like to replicate a couple databases to one of our SQL Server 2005 instances.

The business partner databases that we need to replicate from are only updated daily, so we could certainly use something like log shipping, if that is a possibility. Our databases that we replicate to will be read-only.

What options do we have in this heterogeneous environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do replication between SQL2000 and SQL2005 all the time in our production environment, and it works fine.  Snapshot replication would be appropriate if you only need to replicate the data once a day.

Log shipping from SQL2000 to SQL2005 would probably also work.  (I doubt you could use log shipping from SQL2005 to SQL2000, though, since SQL2000 can't read SQL2005 backups.)